# Convert Numbers To Emoji Math

Tags: code-golf, number

In Emoji Math, a user created module for the video game Keep Talking And Nobody Explodes, numbers are written as strings of emoticons, where each emoticon represents a base 10 digit.
Below is the conversion table between digits and emoticons.

```
Digit | Emoticon
  0   |    :) 
  1   |    =(  
  2   |    (: 
  3   |    )=  
  4   |    :(    
  5   |    ):  
  6   |    =)  
  7   |    (= 
  8   |    :|  
  9   |    |:
```

Given a number, output it in Emoji Math encoding. You may assume the absence of non-numeric characters.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: Are we allowed to take the input number as a string?

Comment: ... Or an array of digits.

Comment: Should we output one of the ten Emoticons with a digit input, or should we output any concatted Emoticons based on an input integer. Or to be more concrete, is `[0,9]` the only valid range of inputs, or can the input also be `>= 10`?

Comment: @Tau sounds like the intention was to accept a string - "You may assume the absence of non-numeric characters."; we should be asking "May we take the input as an integer?"

Comment: Can we assume that the input will be positive? If not, how should we represent zero?

Comment: Since it's encoding, should we support leading 0s?

Comment: What should an input of `0` output?

Comment: I've voted to close as unclear until the points above are addressed. But don't hesitate to ping me once it's fixed so that I can retract my vote or vote to reopen.

Comment: @mbomb007 from the looks of it, `0` should output `:)` since they're in the same row in the table

Comment: @Tau I was asking because of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/185208/convert-numbers-to-emoji-math?noredirect=1#comment444077_185216). The OP needs to answer.

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>29</s> 24 bytes

*-5 bytes thanks to @Shaggy*

```
s":)=((:)=:():=)(=:||:"ò
```

Takes input as a string

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/v1jJStNWQwNIWGloWtlqatha1dRYKR3e9P@/pZmxgYWpkbmJIQA)

Comment: Welcome to Japt :) `m@` can be replaced with `£` to save a byte. But this can be done in [24 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/v1jJStNWQwNIWGloWtlqatha1dRYKR3e9P@/pZmxgYWpkbmJIQA) using base conversion.

Comment: Oops, seems this isn't actually your first Japt solution! You do still qualify for [this bounty](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17410/58974), though, if you want to try for it.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 26 bytes

```
"|:(=):)=:)"2ôºJ2ô`Šr)sSèJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fqcZKw1bTStPWSlPJ6PCWQ7u8gGTC0QVFmsXBh1d4/f9vbgYA)

Comment: This is not working for numbers with multiple digits.

Comment: @izlin: Indeed. I hadn't realized that was part of the challenge. Fixed now though. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>62</s> 58 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to ceilingcat

```c
f(n){n&&write(1,":)=((:)=:():=)(=:||:"+n%10*2,2,f(n/10));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYrBCsIwEAXP9itKwLKvRkzWnjbkYyRYycFFNOKh7bfHePYyDMOk4y2lWmdSLDoMn2cuV/LWCCJRgxAkgqKsq5iD7r0b2bJt/8k7IGw1a@nvl6yEbul2MzFC/3iXFxmD8Auez3/J8dRsq18)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>65</s> 62 bytes

```python
lambda n:''.join(':=():)=(:|)(:=(:)=|:'[int(c)::10]for c in n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DclJCoAwDADAr@SW5CLuS6AvUQ8uFCuaingR/HvtbWCu99m85sGaIRzTOa8TqCAmu3dKKIZY2JB8TNGRn2Dv9KGFRbJ0tP6GBZyCcrjuGGAJu7pI2ypvygw5/A)

Answer (score 4):

## TI-BASIC, 79 bytes

```
Ans→Str1:" :For(I,1,length(Str1:Ans+sub(":)=((:)=:():=)(=:||:",1+2expr(sub(Str1,I,1)),2:End:sub(Ans,2,length(Ans)-1
```

Input is a string of digits in `Ans`.
Output is the Emoji Math-encoded number.

**Examples:**

```
"134
134
prgmCDGF1C
:)(:)=
"2213894
2213894
prgmCDGF1C
(:(:=()=:||::(
```

**Explanation:**

```
Ans→Str1                                                 ;store the input in Ans
"                                                        ;leave " " in Ans
For(I,1,length(Str1                                      ;loop over each character in the
                                                         ; input string
Ans+sub(":)=((:)=:():=)(=:||:",1+2expr(sub(Str1,I,1)),2  ;convert the current character
                                                         ; to a number and use it as the
                                                         ; index into the encoding string
                                                         ; then append the encoded digit
End
sub(Ans,2,length(Ans)-1                                  ;remove the prepended space and
                                                         ; store the result in Ans
                                                         ;implicit print of Ans
```

---

Alternatively, here's a **94 byte** solution that takes a number as input instead of a string:

```
int(10fPart(Ans₁₀^(seq(⁻X-1,X,0,log(Ans→L₁:" :For(I,dim(L₁),1,-1:Ans+sub(":)=((:)=:():=)(=:||:",1+2L₁(I),2:End:sub(Ans,2,length(Ans)-1
```

**Examples:**

```
134
             134
prgmCDGF1C
:)(:)=
2213894
         2213894
prgmCDGF1C
(:(:=()=:||::(
```

**Explanation:**

```
int(10fPart(Ans₁₀^(seq(⁻X-1,X,0,log(Ans→L₁     ;generate a list of the input's digits
                                             ; reversed and store it in L₁
"                                            ;leave " " in Ans
For(I,dim(L₁),1,-1                            ;loop over L₁ backwards
Ans+sub(":)=((:)=:():=)(=:||:",1+2L₁(I),2     ;use the value of the I-th element in L₁ as
                                              ; the index into the encoding string then
                                              ; append the encoded digit
End
sub(Ans,2,length(Ans)-1                       ;remove the prepended space and store the
                                              ; result in Ans
                                              ;implicit print of Ans
```

---

**Notes:**

- TI-BASIC is a [tokenized language](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/tokens).  Character count does ***not*** equal byte count.
- `|` is the two-byte token **0xBBD8** that can only be accessed using [this assembly program](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/hexcodes#toc65).

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 42 bytes

```perl
s/./substr":)=((:)=:():=)(=:||:",$&*2,2/ge
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YX0@/uDSpuKRIyUrTVkMDSFhpaFrZamrYWtXUWCnpqKhpGekY6aen/v9vwGXIZcRlzGXCZcplxmXOZcFl@S@/oCQzP6/4v24BAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [R],  <s>59</s>    48  bytes

different approach:

```
 substr(":)=((:)=:():=)(=:||:",n<-2*scan()+1,n+1)
```

thanks to @aaron for directing me on again :)

original:

```
 el(strsplit(":)x=(x(:x)=x:(x):x=)x(=x:|x|:","x",T))[scan()]
```

beats

```
 c(":)","=(","(:",")=",":(","):","=)","(=",":|","|:")[scan()]
```

by 1 byte

Comment: The different approach is a bit off, you need to add one to the doubled scanned number `2*scan()+1`, with a bit of rearrangement though you can still keep it as 48 bytes. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7g0qbikSEPJStNWQwNIWGloWtlqatha1dRYKenk2egaaRUnJ@ZpaGob6uRpG2r@N/gPAA "R – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## JS ES6, <strike>77</strike> 66 bytes

Down to 66 thanks to suggestions from @Charlie Harding and @asgallant

Had to finally make an account on codegolf since this was such a fun little challenge!

The most minimal form of the original answer, when expecting string-only input:

```
n=>[...n].map(c=>":)=((:)=:():=)(=:||:".match(/../g)[c]).join("")
```

Secondly, my original answer which uses a longer regex and first coerces the input into a string, This works with both number type input and a string of digits input.

> I first coerce the input into a string, which is then destructured into an array using es6 spread. Then I map it through a matcher cb that grabs the correct emoticon from an array made with the regex `/.{1,2}/g`. Finally the resulting array of emoticons is joined back to a string.

```
n=>[...(""+n)].map(c=>":)=((:)=:():=)(=:||:".match(/.{1,2}/g)[c]).join("")
```

JS array stuff is fun. I'm sure there's still some room for optimization, this re-matches the regex on every loop of the `map`.

Crappily tested with the following:

```js
let emoticonize = n=>[...(""+n)].map(c=>":)=((:)=:():=)(=:||:".match(/../g)[c]).join("")

let test = arr => 
console.log(arr.map(x => ({ask:x, ans: emoticonize(x)})))

test([1,40,3697, 2330])
test(["1","40","3697", "2330"])
```

Comment: Why are there spaces around the `=>` arrow in the map? That could save two bytes, couldn't it?

Comment: And I believe the regex `/../g` does the same job too, saving another four bytes

Comment: Finally, if the input is necessarily a string then `[...(""+n)]` can be simplified to `[...n]`, saving a further five bytes

Comment: `map` and regex search is actually costing you characters here; `replace` and `substr` work just as well, with fewer characters: 58 bytes: `n=>n.replace(/./g,c=>':)=((:)=:():=)(=:||:'.substr(2*c,2))`, assuming input as a string of digits.

Comment: man, that's a neat way to use `replace` @asgallant! Seems I gotta get to know my string functions as well :)

Comment: @Roope, feel free to update your answer with the suggestions, and continue to improve upon it if you find a new way to save bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, 80 bytes

```java
n->n.forEach(i->System.out.print(":)=((:)=:():=)(=:||:".split("(?<=\\G..)")[i]))
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ZZDBbsIwDIbvPIXVky3UCDa2sULZaZp2GBeOwCELZZi1oWpSpGnw7J1bMiFtUmLF8R9/v7PXRx3vN5@NybVz8KbZfvcA2Pqs2mqTwbxNAY4H3oDBvchV7TlXzleZLtSr9YvuBJYmojzLluW89mxgDhZSaGw8s2p7qJ612SHHs8WX81mhDrVXZSUojBJKESUkSElKmCanUxIpV@YsRXyapqvVi1IU0ZLXRM2kJ4yyfs@FEVCdwULso/hh@7Fcg6aLdyGjUIDTwQR4Omxjv09dDcBnziN35kMyvLkd3d0/jB8HYaTrQB3l8qJtaMvaB8i/mbpiP0ogCr2tMvh7G5EyO105JFXosv0TjkdjCsq/vXKLwcm5@QE)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->                           // Method with IntStream parameter and no return-type
  n.forEach(i->               //  For each digit `i` in the input:
    System.out.print(         //   Print without newline:
      ":)=((:)=:():=)(=:||:"  //    Push this String
        .split("(?<=\\G..)")  //    Split into parts of size 2
          [i]))               //    And print the `i`'th part
```

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <s>64</s> 56<sub>[Laikoni](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56433/laikoni)</sub> bytes

```
((words":) =( (: )= :( ): =) (= :| |: "!!).read.pure=<<)
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##DcY9CoNAEAbQq3xazRQRBCEwOFUuYJkizaDrD25M2DWk8exO8qo3W15DjP60ZYNi2faQrN/xgBN9X2nIpTCUQAJWCIEFyqD/DxyCsii4SsGG6v1JQduW3ZtrXZ/9GG3Kfrnfuu4H)

#### Ungolfed

Apply the function [`words`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:words) to our space-separated string of symbols `":) =( (: )= :( ): =) (= :| |: "` to get a list, and get the *n*th element [`(!!)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-33--33-) for every *n* in our input string, combining the results. *n.b.* [`(=<<)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-61--60--60-) is equivalent to [`concatMap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concatMap) in this case, mapping a string to a list of strings and concatenating the results.  `read . pure` converts a character to an int, by lifting a character to a string, then [`read`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:read)ing to an int.

```
f x = ((words ":) =( (: )= :( ): =) (= :| |: " !!) . read . pure) =<< x
```

Comment: 56 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcY9CoNAEAbQq3xazRQRBCEwOFUuYJkizaDrD25M2DWk8exO8qo3W15DjP60ZYNi2faQrN/xgBN9X2nIpTCUQAJWCIEFyqD/DxyCsii4SsGG6v1JQduW3ZtrXZ/9GG3Kfrnfuu4H "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 21 bytes

```
“=:)|(”“ØḟƝoṣẈ’ṃs2ị@D
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AT0Awv9qZWxsef//4oCcPTopfCjigJ3igJzDmOG4n8adb@G5o@G6iOKAmeG5g3My4buLQET///8xMDIzNDU2Nzg5)

Answer (score 2):

## [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon), <s>78</s> 75 bytes

```
procedure f(n);s:="";s||:=":)=((:)=:():=)(=:||:"[!n*2+1+:2]&/n;return s;end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYy9DsIwEIN3nuLIgC50oA3ip4nyJIgBtRepAxd0SUFIffcSYOliW58tD13keX5I7KgfhSAga5esV8qlaSputUcsYlFbr9HbQtVlzVtTNZU1182OnVAehSE54n7xdb8NjHoFAPQkecNLhkwYsIYcodW/5s8WMWBTm317OJ2PZfE9/AA)

Answer (score 2):

### [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>87</s>, <s>86</s>, <s>82</s>, 67 bytes

Props to @Artholl and @someone for helping to optimize

```
n=>$"{n}".SelectMany(x=>":)=((:)=:():=)(=:||:".Substring(x*2-96,2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jcq9CsIwFEDh3acoweFeaQtGEEybLKIg6OTgnIZUA/UK@YGK9dljweUs3zGhMsHlYyLTOorl6UDpab3uBtuah/ZKFX0hM0m1ZB/6svpqB2viRdMbRqmYQAkwRwAKiSDFNIl5Sl2I3tEdxhWvdtuSI@ZmcfMu2rMjC3@t9y8yOkIPa75BxCb/AA)

Comment: [You can save 2 bytes](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpdsk5lXolNcUpSZl26nkKZg@z/P1g7C1XPOz0tOLNFQUarOq1XSC07NSU0u8U3Mq9SosLVTstK01dAAElYamla2mhq2VjU1VkBFpUkQzRoaFbomFppaRjpGmpqa1v@tucKLMktSfTLzUjXSNAyNjEGCAA). 1 byte if you use `Substring` instead of `Skip` & `Take` and 1 byte if you hardcode the zero char value.

Comment: @Artholl thank you! Could you show me what you mean by hardcoding the zero char value?

Comment: As you can see in the example. Just write `48` instead of `'0'`.

Comment: Several simple optimizations; 67 bytes. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcpBC4IwFADge79CpMN7oUIGQdMNOhQEdSroPMfTBvaCOUnJfvvy0OU7faZLTWfDsWdTWvbJ6cD9k5yuWirNQzulojqSgaVaxh/@xtmVWjL@onmEQapYoASYEYBCIkgxTWJOfdV5Z7mBYZWnu22SI4ZicXfW09kyAdM7@o8a1vkGs9tr75weARGL8AM "C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Artholl woops my bad didn't see the link

Comment: @someone didn't know changing the type of output was allowed outside of the function

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>64</s> <s>60</s> 59 bytes

<sup>-1 byte thanks to mazzy</sup>

```powershell
-join($args|% t*y|%{':)=((:)=:():=)(=:||:'|% S*g(2*"$_")2})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/V83Kz8zT0MlsSi9uEZVoUSrska1Wt1K01ZDA0hYaWha2Wpq2FrV1FipA6WDtdI1jLSUVOKVNI1qNf/XcnGpqaQpKBkYGhmbmJqZW1gqcSkpQcQMDY2MjI1NTJBElP4DAA)

Takes a string, splits it in `toCharArray`, and then indexes into the emoji key by casting the character to its numerical value, doubles it because each emoji is two wide, and then takes the `substring` from that spot plus one higher. Finally it joins this all up into one string and pushes it to output.

Comment: [59 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/V83Kz8zT0MlsSi9uEZVoUSrska1Wt1K01ZDA0hYaWha2Wpq2FrV1FipA6WDtdI1jLSUVOKVNI1qNf/XcnGpqaQpKBkYGhmbmJqZW1gqcSkpQcQMDY2MjI1NTJBElP4DAA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: @mazzy Yeah, I spaced on how to cast to int without getting the ASCII value, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 87 bytes

```
n=>{for(s=":)=((:)=:():=)(=:||:",i=0;i<20;)n=n.split(i/2).join(s[i++]+s[i++]);return n}
```

Comment: This outputs `):` instead of `(:` for `3`

Comment: @Herman L Yes, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 24 bytes

```
“LƇ§×Yþ’ḃ5$s2ị“:)=(|”ị@D
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9RwxyfY@2Hlh@eHnl436OGmQ93NJuqFBs93N0NlLHStNWoedQwF8hzcPn//7@hkbGJqZm5haUBAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 34 bytes

```
Chop[":)=((:)=:():=)(=:||:",2]&Get
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP2fpmBl@985I78gWslK01ZDA0hYaWha2Wpq2FrV1Fgp6RjFqrmnlvz3S01NKY5WKShITo/lCijKzCsJSS0ucU4sTi2OTtNRMLCyjP0PAA)